# How can I strip comments from HTML with Gulp.js?

Tags: html, gulp

I have just started using gulp.js and I want to know if there is a way to strip out comments from my HTML files. Of course, I don't want the comments removed from the original files, just those that will be in production. Say I have a file like this:

index.html // before gulp

```
<html>
    <!-- Some comments -->
    <!-- Some more comments -->
    <div>
        // some stuff
    </div>
</html>
```

index.html // after gulp

```
<html>
    <div>
        // some stuff
    </div>
</html>
```

Part of my question is that I'm not really sure how this should work. Am I suppose to put all of my gulped HTML files (with comments removed) in a separate directory, and only push that up to my server? I still want the comments to exist in my HTML files on my testing environment (and on my repo), just not on the files that go out to production. Any help in my understanding of how to do this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

with `gulp-htmlmin` you can do it like this:

```
.pipe(htmlmin(
  {
    removeComments: true
  }
))
```

see https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference for all available options.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use [gulp-htmlmin](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gulp-htmlmin) for removing comments among many other optimizations one can do on html files. I have a SRC folder containing the source html files with comments and a BUILD folder that contains all the optimized assets (js, css and html too) and I serve the files from the build folder when in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest way is with [gulp-decomment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-decomment):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var decomment = require('gulp-decomment');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('input.js')
    .pipe(decomment())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-preprocess you can remove the comments.

So you would have one folder - as above - for pre gulp files and one for after it.

Then you could make 2 different tasks. One that only copies the html files and one which copies them and removes the comments.